# Changing the view after addSubview, what is good practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.
Suppose with have this code.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
...
[someScrollView addSubview:label];
...
label.text = @"Some Text";
```

is it good practice to modify the view after addSubview ?
Actually my concern is following probably, it is possible that label get released before reaching to `label.text` assignment, for instance in `viewDidUnload`, right ? and the assignment will fail.

Overall my questions are

- it is good practice to modify views after addSubview ?
- is it good practice to release view after addSubview, and later if I need to get any subview to look for it using following technique `for (UIView *view in self.subviews) { if (...) ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine as long as it is all in the same method and `label` is not reassigned during any of the ... sections.

Modifying a view before or after adding it to a subview makes no difference.

If you have allocated a view, then added it to a subview, and you don't wish to keep a separate reference to it, you should release it - this is standard memory management. The super view will retain its subviews.

To get hold of a reference to your subview again, your two options are:

- Set the tag on the subview before adding it, then use `viewWithTag:` to get it later
- Keep a reference to the subview as an instance variable (in this case, you wouldn't be releasing it after creating it, you'd release it on dealloc).

Answer (score 2):

1. It is fine to change properties of a view after you add it as a subview.  Those properties will be applied (or animated) on the next turn of the runloop when UIKit renders stuff.
2. You should absolutely release your view after adding it as a subview IF you no longer need  to own it.  In other words, follow the memory management guidelines for all cocoa programming.  Doing addSubview will cause the owing view to retain it (since it needs it). If you need to change a property on the view in the future though, you should retain it so you have access to it

Answer (score 0):

- I’ve used both ways - modifying before and after and have not had any issues either way. The superview is retaining the subview, so if you don’t release the superview or set the subview to NIL somewhere, you’re pretty safe.
- Yes, you need to release the view you added after addSubview, but easiest to do it like this:

`UILabel* label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];`

Then it will be released automatically and you don’t have to worry about explicitly releasing it.